# Login Failed for User 'NT AUTHORITY/NETWORK SERVICE' when using EntityDataSource with ASP:ListView

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have receive the infamous Login Failed for User 'NT AUTHORITY/NETWORK SERVICE' when I try to run a page that contains and EntityDataSource and Listview.  Here's Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4846887
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2392
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) +144
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart) +342
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +221
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +189
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +31
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +433
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +499
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +65
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +47

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +168
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +96
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +81
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +46
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +39
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +107
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__2(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +5
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +25
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +43
   System.Linq.Queryable.Count(IQueryable`1 source) +240
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceQueryBuilder`1.Build(ObjectContext context, Boolean computeCount) +154
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, Creator qbConstructor) +889
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +102
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +142
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformSelect() +57
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +73
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +82
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls() +55
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +87
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +44
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842

Here's the contents of my EntityDataSource:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="PartsDataSource" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="name=Diel_inventoryEntities" 
DefaultContainerName="Diel_inventoryEntities" EntitySetName="PartList" 
EntityTypeFilter="PartList" 
Select="it.[PARTNUMBER], it.[NSN], it.[PARTNAME], it.[REV], it.[CUSTOMER]">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Besides creating the .edmx file, listview and entitydatasource, are there any other steps I need to take to resolve this error message?

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that the user NT AUTHORITY/NETWORK SERVICE is used to log on to the database, and is denied. You should either make the website run under a different user account (using impersonation), or change the connection string to specify a sql account/pass. Both solutions require that you create the login in SQL Server, and grant that user the necessary rights.

Comment: I created this user account in SSMS, gave it datareader access and all is now good.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.I encountered the same error with a fresh `IIS` setup. I used :

```
"integrated security=false;User Id=sa;Password=yourpassword"
```